# Do I need hidden buttons for each transition in Spring WebFlow2 on my form

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

Do I need hidden buttons for each transition in Spring WebFlow2 on my form?

I am starting to not like Spring WebFlow2 if this is true. Someone is telling me I need a hidden button for each transition I would like my form to have. Example If I have a form with a submit and reset I understand I should use two buttons.

But if I have a form that needs to kick off a transition to load some data on the form do I really need a button for each transition type? I would found this crazy but is it true?

He is my store. I have a form that the user starts to fill out and once the user clicks on a radio button I need to load a number of schools into a dropdown for the user to pick. The only way I found to do this is to use javascript and a hidden button to kick off the loadschool transition type. example:

**Is this the best way? 
Is this the only way?
Do I really need a button for each transition?**

**My Flow:**

```
<view-state id="SchoolVisitReport" view="SchoolVisitReport.jsp" model="visit" >
<transition on="submit" to="addVisit">
<evaluate expression="flowActions.validateVisit(visit, messageContext)"/>
</transition>

<transition on="loadSchools" to="SchoolVisitReport" >
<evaluate expression="flowActions.initializeSelectableSchool s(visit)" result="flowScope.selectableSchools"/>
</transition>

<transition on="cancel" to="endState" bind="false"/>
</view-state>
```

**My JavaScript:**

```
function loadSchools(strBorough)
{
alert("Loading Schools for borough " + strBorough);
document.visit._eventId_loadSchools.click();

}
```

**My Radio Buttons:**

```
<form:radiobutton tabIndex="9" onchange='loadSchools();' value="B" path="borough" />Bronx-X<BR>
<form:radiobutton tabIndex="10" onchange='loadSchools();' value="K" path="borough" />Kings-K<BR>
<form:radiobutton tabIndex="11" onchange='loadSchools();' value="M" path="borough" />Man.-M<BR>
```

So can someone please tell me if I am doing this the right and best way with webflow2.. thanks

I tried the following code but the form does not get submited

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
          elementId : "borough",
          formId : "visit",
           event : "onChange",
           params : {
                     _eventId : "loadSchools",
                      fragments : "body"}
                    }));
</script>
```

Comment: you need to put an id='borough1' id='borough2' id='borough3' in your radiobuttons if you want the last part to work, and either write the decoration for each of the radiobuttons or use a dojoquery to decore all 3 of them

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need a hidden button to visit a transition. You can simply load the flow execution URL and pass it an `_eventId=loadSchools` parameter. e.g. Something like:

```
window.location='${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=loadSchools'
```

Edit: since you need to pass the form fields too, I think you'll need to do a JavaScript form submission like:

```
function loadSchools(strBorough)
{
    var form = document.forms['yourFormId'];
    form.elements['_eventId'].value = 'loadSchools';
    form.submit();
}
```

(I'm not swearing this is the exact syntax, but hopefully you get the idea.)

Another option would be to load all the schools into the page ahead of time and in your JavaScript simply switch which ones are displayed.

Finally, you might want to investigate [using AJAX](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch12s05.html) rather than full form submission to retrieve the school list.

Comment: doing it the above way will not submit the form and I need access to the data on the form to know which schools to load

Comment: you can submit the form with ajax too.
I see you found a way to ask more questions ;)

Comment: You are passing the values B/K/M to `loadSchools()`, correct?

Comment: I meant to ensure that your `onchange` passes like `loadSchools('B')`. But... I forgot that WebFlow's POST-Redirect-GET pattern doesn't allow form fields to be set via GET. So instead of `window.location` you'll need to use `form.` capabilities.

Comment: I am now trying to use Spring JS and still cant submit page